# Managing sections and field updates between environments

Tags: database, structure

What is the best practice for the following:

Client site running CraftCMS (v3) is in production. Updates are needed which require additions or modifications to the data structure / schema of the site (new sections, fields, etc.). Taking a remote dump of the database for local development is not a realistic option as the client makes regular updates to the website in production. Particularly for new additions, is there a way to easily make those updates in production after I've completed them in my development environment?

Real scenario: I'm adding a new section (a blog) to add to an existing Craft site. I will be working in the development environment for several days, making many additions to the data structure / schema, which I'd prefer not to have to replicate via the admin UI in production once I'm ready to deploy.

*Note: I do **not** want to sync the entire databases - just the structure.*

Comment: Would it be too much work to insert your fields, sections, entrytypes, fieldlayouts and fieldlayoutsfields table to the other database? If you need it more often you could also create a plugin that exports and imports those values via json

Comment: @RobinSchambach great, in theory, but yes more work than seems reasonable. I am looking into the content migrations concept from yii as a potential solution, utilizing the "Migration Manager" plugin to make things a bit easier, because I'm not about to write the migration scripts for all of this. Perhaps this is the solution I'm looking for?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's much work to check 6 select boxes in your DB interface and click on export and import it to your other DB - and an additional step for the content table. A content migration concept by yii2 is much more work since it's only a framework

Answer (score 1):

You could use https://github.com/Pennebaker/craft-architect to export your new sections/entry types/fields from your development environment once you're done, and then import them (without content) to production.

Comment: Great idea. I'll give this a shot. I'm also looking into content migrations as "the" potential solution to this issue, with the help of the "Migration Manager" plugin.